# COUNTIF - establishing a specific range in excel

Tags: excel

i have this formula:

=IF(COUNTIF(C1:C2577,"CertainText")>0, "Present","Absent")

but i dont want it to search in C3, how do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=IF((COUNTIF(C1:C2577,"CertainText")-COUNTIF(C3,"CertainText"))>0, "Present","Absent"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a named range that is defined by the cells C1:C2 and C4:C2577.  Then refer to the named range in your COUNTIF formula.

Comment: Highlight the cells C1:C2, hold down the ctrl key and also highlight the cells C4:C2577.  Click in the GoTo/Address dropdown to the left of the cell editing box at the top of the screen; type in a name for this range of highlighted cells, for example "rng1".  Use the formula: =IF(COUNTIF(rng1,"CertainText")>0, "Present","Absent")